# Techs for building a web-based WYSIWYM XML editor

Tags: xml, wysiwyg, wysiwym

We have a XML schema with a fairly complex grammar for one of our products, for which we need a "basic" graphical editor that is capable of building basic documents based on the schema (complex stuff can always be done programmer-mode).

WYSIWYG is more or less impossible/a waste of time to do meaningfully, so I am investigating WYSIWYM solutions.

Since the application is web-based to begin with, it would be very nice if the editor could be  web-based as well.

I've played with [jaxe](http://jaxe.sourceforge.net/en/) and our schema quite a bit, and is pretty much what I am searching for. However, the configuration facility doesn't give us enough control over how the the document is rendered - the solutions I can come up with leaves us with an XML editor and not a 'document editor', 'yknow. Desire something closer to a WinForms editor à la Visual Studio.

We have a fairly solid vision of what an ideal editor would look like, and (I think) jaxe won't allow us to build it. That, and it isn't web based (no applet).

The [Wymeditor editor](http://www.wymeditor.org/) looks like a fairly solid tool  made for XHTML in a style similar to what we would like, but I suspect that they've built it themselves from scratch - not too keen on that either.

I suppose my question is whether anybody has recommendations on current technologies or approaches that would assist us to build an editor as I've (probably poorly) described?

Comment: Might be going with Xopus ... playing with the demo and its very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [oXygen XML Author](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_author.html)? I'm not completely clear on what you want from the description, but Author may be up your alley. It is not web-based, though.

It's not free, but if you qualify for the Academic/Non-commercial license, the price is very reasonable.